# Eliminar todo los caracteres dentro de <> lenguaje C

Tags: html, c

Me gustaria saber alguna forma de eliminar las letras dentro de <> ya que necesito realizar un programa que sea capaz de limpiar las etiquetas html. Ya realice un programa pero esta algo mal estructurado, apenas estoy iniciando con programación. Además de eliminar las etiquetas, tengo que agregar espacios si la etiqueta es para una palabra en negritas. Mi programa funciona, pero tiene algunos fallos y me gustaría saber alguna otra forma para deshacerme de aquello que esta entre <>.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int c;
    int state = 0;
    int s;
    int i = 0;
    char strong[7]={"strong"};

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){

            if(c == '<'){
                    state == 0;
                    for(s = 0; (c = getchar()) == strong[s]; s++){
                            ;
                    }
                if (s != 6){
                while( (c = getchar()) != '>' ){
                        ;
                }
            }
            else {
                while( c != '>' ){
                        ;
                }
            }
                ++ i;
            if( (c = getchar()) == '<'){
                state == 1;
                while( (c = getchar()) != '>' ){
                    ;
                }
                i++;
            }

        }
        if(c != '<' && c!= '>'){
            i = 0;
        }
           if(state == 0 && i == 0 && s != 6){
            putchar(c);
            i = 0;
           }
           if(s == 6){
                if(c == ' '){
                    printf("_");
                    c = getchar();
                }
            putchar(c);
           }
        if ( c == '>' && s == 6){
            s=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te sugiero pasarte por el [tour] y por [ask] para entender cómo funciona este sitio y cómo elaborar una buena pregunta. Así, por ejemplo, te falta enseñar lo que has intentado. Un saludo

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta para que los demás veamos el programa y poder ver así los fallos. Sino es muy dificil saber exactamente lo que quieres. Pulsa el botón editar y después, en la barra de arriba, tienes para pegar código, sino, usa estas ```

Comment: Sisisi, o sea, es que no se como se llaman, pero la pregunta iba mas enfocada a saber como eliminar algo que esta entre parentesis o lo que sea para ver una mejor opcion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te estás complicando demasiado la vida. En principio solo hay 2 posibles condiciones:

1. Que el caracter actual sea `<` (inicio de etiqueta)
2. Que sea cualquier otro

En el primer caso deberás descartar todo lo que te encuentres hasta dar con el cierre de etiqueta `>`. En el segundo caso, en cambio, te puedes limitar a volcar el caracter:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if(c == '<')
    {
        do
        {
            c = getchar();
        } while(c != EOF && c != '>');
    }
    else
    {
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad si me di cuenta que me estaba complicándome mucho las cosas. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Prueba con "<H1>El uso de < en C</h1>"

Comment: @CandidMoe para esos casos hace falta un intérprete de html, es decir, no solo leer la apertura de la etiqueta sino identificar también si después viene una etiqueta válida ... y por supuesto si la misma está cerrada convenientemente ... yo creo que esos casos se escapan del ámbito de la pregunta

Comment: Además, es posible usar `&lt;` en vez de escribir una falsa apertura de etiqueta